# How to change browser url without page refreshing

Tags: javascript

Please let me know how it can be possible to change url without page refreshing and without using hash tag.

Comment: I want to use same functionality that are in asana task manager use.

Comment: You want the location bar to show `https://BankOfMyCountry.tld` instead of `http://myPhishingSite.tld`? No.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
history.pushState(null, null, '/goto/new/url');
```

if you want to go to relative and new URL.

This is HTML5 history api so will work for modern browsers....
other wise you can fall back to hash urls.....