# change browser url after ajax submit

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

i am trying to learn MVC and in my page there are two actions
1. Update
2. Delete

I did update using submit and delete using AJAX. When delete is successful,i want to redirect to a page. I achieved it but the problem is the URL of browser. It still shows the edit page url. So is there a way i can solve this?

Thanks in advance
Arjun

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20811779/how-to-change-browser-url-without-page-refreshing-in-nodejs/20811867#20811867

Comment: Pardom me if i seems a fool... This works for HTML 5 only rt?

Comment: yes if browser is not supprting history api then you can fallback to hashed url's.

Comment: How you are redirecting to another page ? Try using "window.location.href"

Comment: So, how can i check whether the browser supports it or not.When i tried it in chrome all went ok, but it crashed in IE. So is there a way to identify and set them accordingly

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page

Comment: Kamran, that's the code i implemented. But there is a problem like i specified above. Can you suggest any solutions for that?

Comment: if (history.pushState) {
                        //history.pushState(null, null, '#myhash');
                        window.history.pushState({ "html": response.html, "pageTitle": response.pageTitle }, "", urlPath);
                    }
                    else {
                        window.location.pathname = urlPath;
                        // window.history.pushState({ "html": response.html, "pageTitle": response.pageTitle }, "", urlPath);
                    }   i used this and seems to work. any comments?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried this?

`window.location = '/new/path';`

You fire this code when ajax call is completed. Or even you can pass new url in ajax response.